# Error: relation "django_admin_log" does not exist

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-admin

When I try to log in to admin section I get the error page:

http://localhost:8000/admin/

> ProgrammingError at /admin/ ERROR: relation "django_admin_log" does
> not exist

Then I noticed that 'django_admin_log' table does not exist.

[captured from psql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNGn1.jpg)
I can not remember whether I accidentally removed it or not.

In order to recover it I checked "django.contrib.admin" is in INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'db.apps.DbConfig',
    'django.contrib.postgres',
    'accounts.apps.AccountsConfig',

    'django.contrib.sites',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
   
]
```

and execute "python manage.py migrate admin"

But still, I can not create django_admin_log table.

PostgreSQL version is 12.6

I just mentioned the above settings in this question but still if more code is required then tell me I'll update my question with that information. Thank you

Comment: Did you create the migrations with `python manage.py makemigrations admin` before executing migrate with `python manage.py migrate admin` ?

Comment: Yes, I did it so.

Comment: Did you try `python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb admin` ?